# Postgresql column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to write a script which will take hourly averages of time Series Data. I.e. I have 5 years worth of data at 5 minute intervals, but I need 5 years of hourly averages. Postgresql seems to be complaining about a missing column in the group by clause which is already in there? What schoolboy error am I making here?

```
 SELECT
    time_audit_primary.clockyear,
    time_audit_primary.clockmonth,
    time_audit_primary.clockday,
    time_audit_primary.clockhour,

    AVG (time_audit_primary.time_offset) AS timeoffset,
    AVG (time_audit_primary.std_dev) AS std_dev

    FROM  tempin.time_audit_primary 

    GROUP BY (time_audit_primary.clockyear,
            time_audit_primary.clockmonth,
            time_audit_primary.clockday,
            time_audit_primary.clockhour)
```

Comment: This command works for me. Can you post the table definition and the exact error message?

Comment: Ah!!! Damn, yes works fine without the brackets. Yes postgresl seems quite fussy about parenthesis, same logical position but different position within paragraph even confuses the compiler sometimes it seems.

Comment: It works fine with the parentheses on my PostgreSQL 9.5.

Answer (score 3):

It's the parenthesis around the `group by` columns that is causing the error.  Just remove them:

```
SELECT
    time_audit_primary.clockyear,
    time_audit_primary.clockmonth,
    time_audit_primary.clockday,
    time_audit_primary.clockhour,

    AVG (time_audit_primary.time_offset) AS timeoffset,
    AVG (time_audit_primary.std_dev) AS std_dev

    FROM  tempin.time_audit_primary 

    GROUP BY time_audit_primary.clockyear,
            time_audit_primary.clockmonth,
            time_audit_primary.clockday,
            time_audit_primary.clockhour
```